# How to configure FTP over VPN on an ASA 5505?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

I've configured an IPSec VPN on an ASA 5505 with the mind that all traffic (besides http/s) has to go through this VPN to access the server.

I have also allowed tcp/3389 to pass through the VPN and in doing this, I can connect to 192.168.1.2 using Window's remote desktop client.

When I configure tcp/ftp and tcp/ftp-data in the same way, I'm still unable to connect to 192.168.1.2 with FileZilla.

Are there any special steps I need to take to configure FTP?

NOTE: I'm using ASDM

Comment: You should accept your answer so tht the question doesn't keep popping up, looking for an answer, forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the ASA was configured correctly.

I used the packet trace tool to determine where it was falling over. It's some quirk in IIS. FileZilla Server worked fine though once it was configured for passive mode.

Comment: If you're doing any sort of NAT/PAT on that VPN traffic, you'll need "inspect ftp" to deal with the ip address or port changes as they pass through the ASA.